# Beginner difficulty with vectors and while-loops in C++

Tags: c++

**Update:**

So it turns out there were two issues:

The first is that I checked the [k-1] index before I checked k == 0. This was a crash, although mostly fixable, and not the primary issue I posted about.

The primary issue is that the code seems to execute only after I press ctrl+z. Not sure why that would be.

**Original:**

So, learning from Stroustrup's text in C++ programming, I got to an example on vectors and tried implementing it myself. The gist is that the program user enters a bunch of words, and the program alphabetizes them, and then prints them without repeats. I managed to get working code using a **for** statement, but one of my initial attempts confuses me as to why this one doesn't work.

To be clear, I'm not asking to improve this code. I already have better, working code. I'm wondering here why the code below *doesn't* work.

The "error" I get is that the code compiles and runs fine, but when I input words, nothing happens and I'm prompted to input more.

I'm certain there's an obvious mistake, but I've been looking everywhere for the last 8 hours (no exaggeration) just devoted to finding the error on my own. But I can't.

```
int main() {
    vector<string> warray; string wentry; int k = 0;
    cout << "Enter words and I'll alphabetize and delete repeats:\n\n";
    while (cin >> wentry) warray.push_back(wentry);
    sort(warray.begin(), warray.end());
    while (k < warray.size()) {
    if (warray[k - 1] != warray[k] || k == 0) cout << warray[k] << "\n";
    ++k;
    }
}
```

My reasoning for why this should work is this: I initialize my array of words, my word entry per input, and a variable to index word output.

Then I have a while statement so that every input is stacked at the end of the array.

Then I sort my array.

Then I use my index which starts at 0 to output the 0th item of the array.

Then so long as there are words in the array not yet reached by the index, the index will check that the word is not a repeat of the prior index position, and then print if not.

No matter what whappens, the index is incremented by one, and the check begins again.

Words are printed until the index runs through and checks all the words in the array.

Then we wait for new entries, although this gets kind of screwy with the above code, since the sorting is done before the checking. This is explicitly not my concern, however. I only intend for this to work once.

Comment: `karray[k-1]` when `k == 0` is going to be a problem.

Comment: Please could you do something with the code formatting. eg. one statement per line

Comment: Sorry Ed, when I get frustrated with code I tend to stop caring about making it look readable. :(

Comment: That is no excuse - especially if you are asking people for help

Answer (score 2):

To end the cycle of input you need to insert EOF character which is `ctrl+d`. However, there are other problems in your code. You have `k = 0` to start with so the moment you will try `warray[k - 1]` your code will crash.

Comment: That's why I have an OR statement between warray[k-1] and k == 0. Crashing is not an issue my code has, it just doesn't do anything.

In any case, I don't know what an EOF character is. The code which works also has an index for warray[k-1] OR k == 0, but doesn't have an EOF, but I don't really know what that is.

Comment: There is short circuit evaluation and it will crash. If you are on windows try `ctrl+z` in console.

Comment: `ctrl+z` on Windows and `ctrl+d` on Unix send `EOF` i.e. end-of-file character. It indicates end of input. Its value is defined as -1 which is two characters so you cannot input it like that.

Comment: How would I program it to end of file on its own, without me having to input ctrl+z?

Comment: You have to have some terminating condition. There should be some input on which you would like to stop. If you think of such input then appropriate code can be written.

Comment: Thanks for your help, user. One more question: Since the cout << ... is under the while-loop, shouldn't it print even if the program doesn't terminate? Since it's executing while things are happening.

Comment: `k==0` will pass for first iteration and first word should be printed. Then k will become 1 and kth(as in index starting from 0 for vector) word will be printed if and only if the second condition is satisfied i.e. `warray[k-1] != warray[k]`

Comment: But no words are printed when I compile and run.

Comment: Look carefully. It does print first word for me.

Comment: I'm certain that no words are being printed. (I mean, obviously except when I ctrl+z, although the cout command is under the while loop.) Now I'm confused again.

Answer (score 2):

At the point where you take

`warray[k - 1]`

for the first time, k is zero, so you want to get the warray value at index -1, which is not necessarily defined in memory (and even if, I wouldn't do this anyway). So as it compiles, I guess the address is defined in your case by accident.

I would try simply reversing the OR combination in your if-condition:

```
 if (k == 0 || warray[k - 1] != warray[k])
```

thus for the first iteration (k == 0) it won't check the second condition because the first condition is then already fulfilled.

Does it work then?

Comment: It prevented a crash, but it wasn't the primary issue. Apparently pressing ctrl+z caused everything to "fix".

Comment: One more thing: Your main function is defined to return an integer, but it doesn't. Try putting "return 0;" at the end, before the }.

Comment: That's because I'm new to C++ and all programming in general. I'm parroting Stroustrup when I type int main(). What should I use, then? void main()?

Comment: Yes, you could use void main() instead. (Thus no returned value will be expected by the machine.)

Comment: No you should not use `void main`. `int main()` is the standard function in ISO specification.

Comment: @nothingness: `int main()` is correct. `void main()` is not. If you don't have an explicit return when you leave `main()`, there is an implicit `return 0;`

Comment: @BillLynch: ahh ok, I didn't know of the implicit return statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're stuck in the while loop because you don't have a way of breaking out of it. That being said, you can use Ctrl + d (or use Ctrl + z if executing on windows in the command prompt) to break out of the loop and continue executing the code.

As for while loop at the bottom which prints out the sorted vector of values, your program is going to crash as user902384 suggested because your program will first check for warray[k - 1].

Ideally, you want to change the last part of your program to:

```
while (k < warray.size()) 
{
    if (k == 0 || warray[k - 1] != warray[k]) 
        cout << warray[k] << "\n";
    ++k;
}
```

This way, the k == 0 check passes and your program will skip checking warray[k - 1] != warray[k] (which would equal warray[-1] != warray[0] when k=0).

Comment: Not stuck per say, but this line:
    while (cin >> wentry) warray.push_back(wentry);

Continues to execute until a break is entered. Looking at the edit from side1066 he was running through Command Prompt on windows so he needed to use Ctrl + z to break out of the loop.

You could alternatively add code to check for an exit input, that would execute a break statement if matched.

Comment: I compiled the code in VS2013 and I can keep hitting enter and it continues to loop through. It's not counting as a fail when I try running it, although the blank lines aren't added to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

You just needed to reverse:

```
if (warray[k - 1] != warray[k] || k == 0)
```

to

```
if (k == 0 || warray[k - 1] != warray[k] )
```

for terminating this condition if `k` = 0.

## An alternative.

Although it can termed as a bit off topic, considering you want to work with `std::vector<>`, but `std::set<>` is an excellent container which satisfies your current two conditions:

1. Sort the `strings` in alphabetical order.
2. Delete all the repetitions.

Include `<set>` in your `.cpp` file, and create a `set` object, `insert` all the `std::string` and iterate through the set to get your ordered, duplicate-free strings!

The code:

```
int main() {
   //Define a set container.
   set<string> s;
   //A temporary string variable.
   string temp;
   //Inserting strings into the set.
   while (cin >> temp) s.insert(temp);
   //Create a set<int> iterator.
   set<string>::iterator it;
   //Scanning the set
   for(it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it)
   {
     //To access the element pointed by the iterator,
     //use *it.
     cout<<*it<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I just recommended this container, because you will study `set` in Stroustrup's text, and it is very easy and convenient instead of laboring over a `vector`.

Comment: Why do you use warray.size() - 1 to compare to the index k? This way the last item in the vector, which is of index warray.size() - 1, is not checked by the if-statement.

Comment: I have edited the whole thing, I realised I was wrong. Thanks a lot for correcting me. @side1066